# Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Active Directory

Tags: samba, directory, authentication

I've been following the “SSSD and Active Directory” documentation in order to try and add an Ubuntu Server to our Windows AD domain for user authentication.

Configuration goes well until the point at which I need to start the SSSD service.

The service will not start, it after checking `journalctl` the following error is given:

> Failed to read keytab [default]: No such file or directory

I would guess this is being caused by:

```
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
```

inside `/etc/samba/smb.conf` but no information is given in the documentation about other possible values this method can be set to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: when you restart the services in the [how-to guide](//help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html) you can’t start the SSSD daemon cause the error. Just join your machine to your AD how the next steps describe. After that start SSSD.

In addition, add

```
ldap_id_mapping = true
```

to your `sssd.conf` if you don’t have Unix IDs in your AD, so SSSD calculates the IDs.

Comment: You didn't have to create a new account just to post a slightly different answer to this question after the first one was deleted. You could have edited it before or after it was deleted/hidden and asked a moderator to undelete it.